# Low visibility in progress and low visibility in force

Tags: air-traffic-control, visibility

Are Low visibility in progress and low visibility in force different?

Comment: Where did you encounter these terms?

Comment: Atis of different airports. Some of them low visibility in progress some of them low visibility in force

Comment: We use "Low visibility procedures in operation". Same thing :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe that these two terms most likely refer to the same thing, namely:

*Low Visibility **Procedures** (LVPs) are in force at this Aerodrome.*

---

> Low visibility procedures (LVP): Specific procedures applied at an
> aerodrome for the purpose of ensuring safe  operations during Category
> II and III approaches and/or low visibility take-offs.
>
> *ICAO Doc 9365, Manual of All-Weather Operations*

Your first statement, "low visibility is in progress", lacks clarity and objective criteria to define what constitutes "low visibility." Without specific parameters, such as visibility distance thresholds or industry standards, it is difficult to determine the extent of low visibility. Visibility can vary depending on factors like the airport's definition, airline policies, and prevailing weather conditions. To ensure clarity and precision, it is important to establish clear criteria for low visibility, such as specific visibility distances, meteorological conditions, or adherence to internationally recognised standards. This allows for a more accurate and consistent assessment of low visibility conditions at airports.

Hence why I believe that you are inquiring about the defined “Low Visibility Procedures” in which, when in place, an airport changes its operations. For example procedures for taxi operations, holding points, ground lighting etc etc. (For further info see: ICAO Doc 9476, Manual of Surface Movement Guidance and Control Systems or [Skybrary Low Visibility Procedures in the context of EASA regulations](https://skybrary.aero/articles/low-visibility-procedures-lvp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "low visibility in progress" and "low visibility in force" are different terms used to describe different stages of low visibility conditions.

"Low visibility in progress" typically refers to a situation where visibility is gradually decreasing or becoming worse. It suggests that the conditions are deteriorating and may continue to worsen.

On the other hand, "low visibility in force" indicates that low visibility conditions are already present and have reached a certain level of severity. It suggests that the conditions are currently in effect and may persist for a period of time.

In summary, "low visibility in progress" suggests a developing situation with decreasing visibility, while "low visibility in force" indicates that the low visibility conditions are already present and ongoing.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?